# Store an ArrayList of custom objects

Tags: android, sqlite, serialization, storage, sharedpreferences

I have an array of custom objects called AccActivity.

```
public class AccActivity {
    AccData Data;
    AccData fData;
    AccData lpfData;

    int[] crossings;
    float[] sd;
    int type = -1;
    private float[] minMax;
    float spread = 0.30f;
    int rate = 8;
    float alpha = 0.30f;
    float avResAcc;
    float[] peakDistances;
    int[] peakNumber;
    ArrayList<Integer> peakIndicesX;
    ArrayList<Integer> peakIndicesY;
    ArrayList<Integer> peakIndicesZ;
```

And the AccData object looks like this:

```
public class AccData {
    private ArrayList<Float> xData;
    private ArrayList<Float> yData;
    private ArrayList<Float> zData;
    private float[] averageNoise;
```

Now, I have researched the problem on the internet and apparently there are three options of storing data in android - all of them seem not to be suitable for me

SharedPrefs - no, because its for storage of primitive key value preferences

Serialisation - saving to file - not sure - I only saw examples where it was used on non-custom object types, how would I come around it?

SQLite - no, another answer on stack overflow said:
"How can I store my custom object in a database ?

You don't, unless you are using an object database. You store a representation of the object in a database."

What is this object database that they mention?

Can somebody tell me how to save and retrieve this arrayList that I'm having?

EDIT: I don't care about SDK compatibility and can select the highest one as this is an individual research project

EDIT2: Goal: After turning the phone off and back on, I want the ArrayList data to be automatically retrieved when I open the app.

Answer (score 1):

You can very well use `Serialization`. In case of custom objects, ensure that your custom object `implements` the `Serializable` interface, and any custom object within that object, should also be `Serializable`.

**E.g:-**

```
class CustomObject implements Serializable
{
     public String name;
}

ArrayList<CustomObject> objectList = new ArrayList<CustomObject>();
```

So `objectList` is now Serializable and you can also pass this between activities in the `Intent`.

Comment: I tried using method from this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640122/save-an-arraylist-to-file-on-android

but for some reason it did not work.

Comment: I don't want to pass between activities, I want the data to be there after I turn the phone off and back on

Comment: `some reason` is a bit too vague. If you've the whole error stack trace, can try to help you out with it.

Comment: You can **also** pass, whether you want to pass or not, is upto you. But it'll be persisted in the device and you can read it back later.

Comment: I have put this:

  `String ser = SerializeObject.ReadSettings(this, "myobject.dat");
  if (ser != null && !ser.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
      Object obj = SerializeObject.stringToObject(ser);
      // Then cast it to your object and 
      if (obj instanceof ArrayList) {
          // Do something
          activityLibrary = (ArrayList<AccActivity>)obj;
      }
  }`

Into onCreate method and....

Comment: ... and this into the save method 
`String ser = SerializeObject.objectToString(activityLibrary);
if (ser != null && !ser.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
    SerializeObject.WriteSettings(this, ser, "myobject.dat");
} else {
    SerializeObject.WriteSettings(this, "", "myobject.dat");
}`


The only thing I dont understand, is what is "act" variable - this is some context but it is not precised in answer

Answer (score 1):

You can serialize each array in AccData to [JSON](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html) and store it in [SQLite database](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db).

Answer (score 0):

Answering your object database questions, there are at least 2 object databases which work on Android - [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/android/) and [Perst](http://www.mcobject.com/android).

Comment: I am very new to android programming, I don't even know where to start with databases but I appreciate links.