# Simplest way to write an arraylist to a textfile in Java

Tags: java, android, persistence

I have a `static ArrayList<String> items` which is shown via listview after it gets populated with elements.

What is the easiest way to to save the arraylist and/or listview to a textfile?

Comment: I think, you should check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111496/java-how-can-i-write-my-arraylist-to-a-file-and-read-load-that-file-to-the) answer.

Comment: hm i tried it tbh but to no avail. maybe its because i used an arrayadapter.
https://gyazo.com/ace5e232e9cebe53d3d8f236941d1842

Answer (score 0):

I've done it this way. But the body here is JSON String.

```
public void saveTextFile(Context context, String sFileName, String sBody) {
    try {
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File filePath = new File(root + "/Personal Encyclopedia/Data" + File.separator);
        if (!filePath.exists()) {
            filePath.mkdirs();
        }
        File writeFile = new File(filePath, sFileName);
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(writeFile, true);
        writer.append(sBody);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Make your `ArrayList` a string (possible by overriding `toString()` method) and call with file name `YourFileName.txt`. May be it is helpful

Comment: thx for ur answers guys.. i sort of did it but the output is a string and not a listview (which i guess is difficult to do). Used different code :
https://gyazo.com/bfd329d0ba9d43040935d964a226d42c

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at the [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html).