# Create text file in a specific folder android

Tags: java, android

I have made a folder named "files" in the package of my app.
Now I want to create a text file in that folder on the click of button.
The file should open in **append mode** and a List or **ArrayList** should be written in that file.

Also how do I read **ArrayList** from that file and print it?

Comment: Try to write code for start, and then show to us your errors

Answer (score 0):

This is a very generic question, so this will be a very generic answer:

-See here for details on saving files, using internal/extrernal storage etc: 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

-To append to a file use the right mode:
openFileOutput("file.dat", MODE_APPEND | MODE_WORLD_READABLE );

-to put an arraylist to file and retrieve it you should serialize it:
[Save an ArrayList to File on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640122/save-an-arraylist-to-file-on-android)